# mac high sierra directory path in terminal

Tags: terminal, macos-high-sierra

I am doing something very simple in `Scala`.  I wrote a short program and have it saved in file `ScalaTutorial.scala` which is in my downloads directory.

Using the `Mac High Sierra` terminal, I cam trying to compile my program.  at the prompt, I have:

> scalac /Macintosh\ HD/Users/myName/Downloads/ScalaTutorial.scala

However, I get an error:

```
error: source file '/Macintosh HD/Users/myName/Downloads/ScalaTutorial.scala' could not be found.
```

While I am obviously referring to the file location incorrectly, it is not clear to me how I should refer to the file location.  I have tried with and without the leading '/', I have tried enclosing the location in quotes, and I have not seen an example surfing the web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just need:

```
scalac /Users/myName/Downloads/ScalaTutorial.scala
```

The `Macintosh HD` volume would normally be mounted at the root, so you just need `/` to access it.

It would also be accessible under `/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/`, but `/` is more-direct and will work if you change the volume name.

Simpler still, you can most-likely use `~/` to get to your home directory:

```
scalac ~/Downloads/ScalaTutorial.scala
```